# How to create multiple language files in i18n-node?

Tags: node.js, express, i18n-node

I work with Node+Express+i18n-node.
My project's a translation file will have about 5000 (rows) translations. I would like to split info in separate files:

```
locales
    --en
    ----forms.json
    ----userinterface.json (about 1500 rows)
    ----administratorintercace.json (about 2000 rows)
    ....
```

I18n-node has one language file (en.json) by default. But I wouldn't like to load in server memory 5000 rows, when each user loading page. User shouldn't load all information from administratorinterface file.
I can't find info about this salution. And I don't want to install i18-next module.